# Changing the bilinear form on a Euclidean space with an orthonormal basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I'm having trouble getting my head around how Euclidean spaces, bilinear forms and dot product all link in with each other. I am told that on a Euclidean space any bilinear form is denoted by $$\tau(u,v) = u\cdot v$$ and in an orthonormal basis we have $$u \cdot v = \underline{u}^T \underline{v}$$ but what, say, if we have an orthonormal basis on a vector space together with a positive definite symmetric bilinear form (so a Euclidean space) then $$\tau(u,v) = \underline{u}^T \underline{v}$$ but what now if we keep the same vector space, the same orthonormal basis, and the same vectors $u,v$ but we *change* the positive definite symmetric bilinear form $\tau$ surely the computation $\underline{u}^T \underline{v}$ will be the same but the computation $\tau(u,v)$ will surely change? Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orthonormal is defined with respect to $\tau$.  That is, with no positive definite symmetric bilinear form $\tau$ around, the statement "$\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a an orthonormal basis" is meaningless.

Once you have such a $\tau$, then you can say $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis *with respect to $\tau$*."  This means that $\tau(v_i,v_i) = 1$ and $\tau(v_i, v_j) = 0$ when $i\neq j$.

Often, once a $\tau$ has been chosen, one doesn't write "with respect to $\tau$", but technically it should always be there.

So, when you say

> > ...what now if we keep the same vector space, **the same orthonormal basis**, and the same vectors u,v but we change the positive definite symmetric bilinear form τ surely the computation $\underline{u}^T\underline{v}$ will be the same but the computation $\tau(u,v)$ will surely change

(emphasis mine) you have to be careful because you can't stick with the same orthonormal basis.  When you change $\tau$, this changes whether or not your orthnormal basis is still orthonormal.  So before computing $\underline{u}^T\underline{v}$, you must first find a new orthonormal basis, then compute $u$ and $v$ in this basis, and then compute $\underline{u}^T\underline{v}$.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand, thank you